# Is this series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{n}{2n^2-1})^2$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

Is the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{n}{2n^2-1})^2$ convergent?

My attempt:

The series is convergent iff $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k}$ convergent.
Then we need to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^k (\frac{2^k}{2\times2^k-1})^2$ converges.
I want to find a series that bigger than the above series, but don't know what to do.
Can someone help me with that?
Or does root test works in this case?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n}{2n^2-1}\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course because for $n\rightarrow+\infty$ $$\frac{\frac{n^2}{(2n^2-1)^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{4}$$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges (to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$).

Also, we have $$\sum_{n=2}\frac{n^2}{(2n^2-1)^2}<\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$